# pytest: Generator cannot be collected (takes exactly 1 argument 0 given)

Tags: python, python-2.7, pytest

I am trying to assemble a minimal test suite using pytest. I want my test to use one fixture, and I want to use generator-like tests.
Let my suite consist of these two files:

> conftest.py

```
import pytest


@pytest.fixture
def fix1():
    return 100
```

and

> test_test.py

```
import pytest


def test_1(fix1):
    assert fix1


def test_2(fix1):
    assert fix1
    yield 200


@pytest.mark.gen_test
def test_3(fix1):
    assert fix1
    yield 200
```

What happens is: `test_1` is collected and successfully executed, but `test_2` and `test_3` are failed to collect. The error I recieve is:

```
test_test.py:None (test_test.py)
self = <CallInfo when='collect' exception: test_2() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)>
func = <function <lambda> at 0x7f9fe442b0c8>, when = 'collect'

    def __init__(self, func, when):
        #: context of invocation: one of "setup", "call",
        #: "teardown", "memocollect"
        self.when = when
        self.start = time()
        try:
>           self.result = func()

/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/runner.py:196: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/runner.py:375: in <lambda>
    lambda: list(collector.collect()),
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

self = <Generator 'test_2'>

    def collect(self):
        # test generators are seen as collectors but they also
        # invoke setup/teardown on popular request
        # (induced by the common "test_*" naming shared with normal tests)
        from _pytest import deprecated
        self.session._setupstate.prepare(self)
        # see FunctionMixin.setup and test_setupstate_is_preserved_134
        self._preservedparent = self.parent.obj
        l = []
        seen = {}
>       for i, x in enumerate(self.obj()):
E       TypeError: test_2() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/python.py:597: TypeError
```

What should be the right recipe for using fixtures with generators in pytest?

P. S. program versions:

> pytest: 3.2.3; python: 2.7.14

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?
[pytest-tornado examples](https://github.com/eugeniy/pytest-tornado) only show gentest with pytest-tornado fixtures, not other fixtures.

Comment: In my case, my particular test suite required pytest-tornado package installed, and I had it missing. If you have pytest-tornado in your python environment, it defines its own `pytest.mark.gen_test` decorator, and the above example works properly.

Comment: Hah, I had done the same. I didn't realise py.test also defined the `gen_test` decorator, so when it worked I assumed pytest-tornado was installed.